# When printing multiple documents the first one goes to the wrong printer

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I have to programmatically create and print multiple documents(Labels).  My code creates and prints every label except the first one correctly; which is sent to the default printer, not the specified printer.  Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
Do While ....
txt = sometext
PrintDocument1.Print()
Loop

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
Dim prFont As New Font("Arial Narrow", 19, FontStyle.Bold)
Dim format As New StringFormat
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\TLN-CESDC2\TLN2-41-LABEL"
e.PageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 20
e.PageSettings.Margins.Left = 0
e.PageSettings.Margins.Right = 0
e.PageSettings.Margins.Top = 20
e.Graphics.DrawString(txt, prFont, Brushes.Black, 200, 15, format)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the printer before starting the loop:

```
PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\TLN-CESDC2\TLN2-41-LABEL"
Do While ....
  txt = sometext
  PrintDocument1.Print()
Loop
```

See [PrintDocument.PrinterSettings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This worked perfectly.  It seems to be a more correct method as well because I am only setting the printer one time instead of dozens of times.